# fixed positioning of an image at the bottom of a DIV

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a div (or article or section..) where the main content of the page is shown. (inc.: text, images, paragraphs et al).

What I want is:
I want an image top be position at the bottom part of this div. BUT:

If the DIV's height is longer than the browser window's, I want this image to be position at the bottom of the position viewport where it is always visible to the user.

If the DIV's height is shorter than the browser window's viewport, than I want this image to be positioned wherever the DIV's bottom end is located.

EX. 1- DIV is longer than the viewport, so the bottom image is fixed at the bottom of the viewport

**The image is represented with -> ...**

```
==================
=   ______       =
=  |      |      =
=  | DIV  |      = 
=  |      |      =  --> VIEWPORT FRAME
=  |      |      =
=  |...   |      =
==================
   |      |      
   |      |      
   |------|
```

EX. 2- DIV is shorter than the viewport, so the bottom image is fixed at the bottom of the DIV

**The image is represented with -> ...**

```
==================
=   ______       =
=  |      |      =
=  | DIV  |      = 
=  |...   |      =
=  |------|      =
=                =
==================
```

I can achieve this with JavaScript, of course. But I would like to instead find out if this is achievable with using extra layer DIVs or wrappers or other sorts of CSS positioning. ]

If CSS-HTML way is not possible, what would be the best JS logic to employ to get this done?

1) Page loaded: compare height's and position the image accordingly and if scrolling is done re-calculate and re-position?

Thank you.

Comment: You'll definitely have to use javascript/jquery, this is something css just can't do.

Answer (score 1):

Don't quote me on this as I'm not 100% certain but maybe you could change the positioning of the DIV from relative to absolute dynamically using JQuery.

I'm thinking something like if it is not in view

```
position: absolute;
bottom: 0px;
```

else

```
position: relative;
bottom:0px;
```

That way the absolute position would fix it to the bottom of the page, otherwise the relative positioning would fix it to the bottom of its parent div.

If you create a fiddle I (or anyone else) could have a little play around with this for you.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I'm fairly sure the `position: relative; bottom: 0px;` combo will not move the image anywhere, since you're moving it `0px` relative to where it is normally rendered.

Comment: The outcome is nothing yes, but by changing one CSS attribute it removes the effects of the absolute positioning. What did you decide to do in the end Phil?

Comment: Sure, but in that case you should probably set it to `static` instead of `relative`, since that's the actual default.  But it doesn't really matter unless you care about convention.

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for the idea Rick. I think I will do as you say and just modify the position attribute but it probably will be between relative and fixed, since absolute pushes it to the end of the document, not viewport. I think I will use jQuery .scroll to see if bottom of div is out or in the viewport and then switch the position attribute.